# How to collect monitor and collect data on Perfino without UI?

Tags: java, jprofiler, javaagents, catalina, perfino

I am hesitate to use Perfino UI on the production environment. I want to run the agent as commandline interface and passing a command to collect and send the snapshot to me. Everything i need to do without any UI? Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

Please check

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/perfino/help/doc/main/architecture.html

for the architecture.

No UI is required for the perfino agent. The agent collects data and sends it to the perfino collector. The collector writes the cumulated data to an internal database. There are no snapshots that you can send around.

You should rather use JProfiler and offline profiling for your purpose.

Comment: @ion kegal how can i make use of the stored data on the database until it send it from porduction environment to dev for analysis?

Comment: @ion kegal Here is the situation : I have a production server where the perfino agent is running without UI. How do i get the data from the server to my machine so i can read it using JProfiler.